# Running scripts on package.json

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules, package.json

I'm working on a large codebase and I'm trying to run scripts from the package.json file it looks like this:

[image]

now whenever I run "npm start" it goes to the dev script then it throws me an error:

[image]

but I found a way with this one I changed the ./node_modules/.bin/webpack to "dev": "webpack serve . . ."

and it works

But the problem is I would mess-up the codebase if I apply some changes on the package.json

I hope you can help me with this

Answer (score 0):

The error stating that . is not recognized is coming from Command Prompt and not PowerShell. You should either refactor those commands to work with Command Prompt or make a seperate script that doesn't run with npm.